# Why is my Google Cloud Load Balancer, pointed at a bucket, only hosting the index.html file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I have the following in my LB

[image]

And then I have the bucket mapped

[image]

The Bucket looks like this...

[image]

[image]

When I run `curl https://me.com -v`

I get the HTML file in index.html which I would expect but when I call `https://me.com/assets/index-2898da6d.js` but this also comes back with the result of index.html instead of the JS file. I did not setup the original bucket so I may be missing a hook or something pointing it directly but how would I change this so it follows the path appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Hi `Jose Gleeson` there might be some permission mismatch check whether there are required roles configured perfectly and you can also follow this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-webapp-hosting-gcs#6) and official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) for more information.

Comment: About permission, Is your bucket in uniform IAM permission mode?

Comment: Sorry @guillaumeblaquiere are you asking me or `Jose Gleeson`. In my case I have assigned a SA with the storage object viewer role as mentioned in that documentation and tutorial.

Comment: it's for you @kranthiveer-dontineni. In supplement of the Jose supposition about the permission. I understood the role you put, but is the bucket in uniform IAM mode or legacy?

Comment: I have used uniform access level as it's not for production @guillaumeblaquiere